# Trying to use Imagemagick to convert an RGB image into a list of hex codes, each for every pixel

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

As the title states, I'm attempting to make a script which reads an image, doesn't matter the resolution, and converts the image into a list of hex codes. For example, an 8x8 PNG Image with alternating white and black pixels would be converted into this:

```
FFFFFF
000000
FFFFFF
000000
FFFFFF
000000
```

And so on. I've tried the following so far:

```
convert $name.png -compress none pnm:-
```

However, the above code returned just regular numbers instead of hex values. Here's an example:

```
205 0 0 205 0 0 205 0 0 205 0 0 205 0 0 205 0 0 224 160 0 224 160 0 224 160 0
```

What went wrong here, and what changes would I make to it to make it output hex codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
convert yourimage.png txt:- | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*#\([0-9A-Fa-f]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt

Answer (score 2):

You could use **ImageMagick** to decode the file to raw RGB values and **xxd** to group them and display in hex:

```
convert yourImage.png rgb:- | xxd -g3
```

I use `-g3` to group into threes for RGB files, and if there is an alpha/transparency layer:

```
convert yourImage.png rgba:- | xxd -g4
```

Other switches you might like to use with `xxd` would be:

```
xxd -g3 -c15    # 15 bytes per line, good if you have 5 pixels of 3 bytes each, so hex lines match image scanlines

xxd -ps         # continuous output without offsets at start of lines
```